# Cannot find the correct way to change string time to datetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a df column with the following days example `2018-07-25 19:23:17.000000`
 and i cannot find the correct way to convert this string into a datetime value

I've been trying with the following code

```
 dfa['time_event_utc'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time_event_utc'],format='%d%b%Y:%H:%M:%S +000000',utc=True)
```

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: ValueError: time data '2018-07-01 01:11:33.000000' does not match format '%d%b%Y:%H:%M:%S +000000' (match)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your format is `'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'`

```
mydt = '2018-07-25 19:23:17.000000'
datetime.datetime.strptime(mydt , '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
```

Comment: `%m` lowercased